# calling of one form from another form in sencha2.0 using card layout

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am working on sencha2.0. I have one login form and I want to call another form on click of submit button present in login form.I wish to use card layout for the same in which one form will be one item for the card and other form as another item for the card. I am clear about the logic but need some similar kind of example for its reference. Can you provide me some nice examples for reference of the same?Kindly help me finding problem in below code:

```
Ext.define('senchaApp.view.activation', {
    extend : 'Ext.Container',
    xtype : 'activation',
    requires: "Ext.form.FieldSet",
    id : 'activation',


    constructor : function(config) {
        var formContainer = Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{

            id:'formPanel',
            layout:'card',
            fullscreen:'true',
            items:[{
                xtype:'fieldset',
                title:'Login',
                items:[
                       {xtype:'textfield',
                        name:'name',
                        id:'name',
                        label:'Name',
                        clearIcon:false,
                        cls:'fields'
                        },
                        {xtype:'emailfield',
                            style:'margin-top:10px;',
                            name:'email',
                            id:'email',
                            label:'Email',
                            clearIcon:false,
                            cls:'fields'
                        },
                            {xtype:'emailfield',
                            style:'margin-top:10px;',
                            name:'reTypeEmail',
                            id:'reTypeEmail',
                            label:'Retype Email',
                            clearIcon:false,
                            cls:'fields'
                        },
                            {xtype:'passwordfield',
                            style:'margin-top:10px;',
                            name:'pass',
                            id:'pass',
                            label:'Password',
                            clearIcon:false,
                            cls:'fields'
                        },
                            {xtype:'passwordfield',
                            style:'margin-top:10px;',
                            name:'reTypePass',
                            id:'reTypePass',
                            label:'Retype Password',
                            clearIcon:false,
                            cls:'fields'
                        },
                        {xtype:'numberfield',
                            style:'margin-top:10px;',
                            name:'mobilePhone',
                            id:'mobilePhone',
                            label:'Mobile Phone',
                            clearIcon:false,
                            cls:'fields'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype:'textfield',
                            name:'secretQuestion',
                            id:'secretQuestion',
                            style:'margin-top:10px;',
                            label:'Secret Question',
                            clearIcon:false,
                            cls:'fields'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype:'textfield',
                            name:'secretAnswer',
                            id:'secretAnswer',
                            label:'Secret Answer',
                            style:'margin-top:10px;',
                            clearIcon:false,
                            cls:'fields',
                        },
                        {
                            xtype:'numberfield',
                            style:'margin-top:10px;',
                            name:'authCode',
                            id:'authCode',
                            label:'Auth Code',
                            clearIcon:false,
                            cls:'fields'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype:'button',
                            style:'margin-top:10px;float:right;width:10%;',
                            cls:'next',
                            id:'next',
                            text:'Next',
                            ui:'action-round',
                            action:'next',
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {   xtype:'fieldset',
                    title:'Activation',
                    items:[
                            {
                            xtype:'textfield',
                            name:'user',
                            id:'user',
                            label:'Username',
                            clearIcon:false,
                            cls:'fields'
                            },
                            {xtype:'passwordfield',
                            style:'margin-top:10px;',
                            name:'pass',
                            id:'pass',
                            label:'Password',
                            clearIcon:false,
                            cls:'fields'
                            },
                            {xtype:'button',
                            cls:'submitBtn',
                            id:'submit',
                            ui:'action-small',
                            action:'submitLogin',
                            style:'background-image: url("app/resources/images/img_btnStrip.png");width:186px;margin: 0 auto;height:66px;margin-top:20px;background-color:none;'
                            }
                          ]
                }
            ]
        });

        var formContentHolder = Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{

            cls:'middleContainer',
            items:[formContainer]
        });





        config.items = [formContentHolder];

        this.callParent(arguments);
    },

    initialize : function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }

});
```

Below mentioned is the code for Main.js under controller:

```
Ext.define('senchaApp.controller.Main',{
    extend:'Ext.app.Controller',



    init: function(){
        Ext.create('senchaApp.view.Viewport');

            this.control({
                '#submit':{
                    tap: this.showIndicesOverlay
            }
        });
    },
    showIndicesOverlay: function(){
        Ext.getCmp('activation').setActiveItem(1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your Container with `layout: 'card'` and `id: 'your-container-id'` has 2 items:

```
items: [
  {xtype: 'login-form'},
  {xtype: 'another-form'},
]
```

Then when the submit button of your login form is tapped, after doing whatever you want, just use `Ext.getCmp('your-container-id').setActiveItem(1)`

The easiest way as far as I know. Hope this helps.

Comment: Kindly revisit the question and let me know where I am doing the mistake/

Comment: I can't see any form coming up on the screen(screen comes blank) and errors that comes are: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
toolbar-buttons-1.jsFailed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)